# plt.figure() vs subplots in Matplotlib

Tags: python, graph, matplotlib, plot

In **Matplotlib** a lot of examples come in the form `ax = subplot(111)` and then functions are applied on `ax`, like `ax.xaxis.set_major_formatter(FuncFormatter(myfunc))`. (found [here](http://www.mail-archive.com/matplotlib-users@lists.sourceforge.net/msg05474.html))

Alternatively, when I don't need subplots, I can just do `plt.figure()` and then plot whatever I need with `plt.plot()` or similar functions.

Now, I'm exactly in the second case, but I want to call the function `set_major_formatter` on the X axis. Calling it on `plt` of course won't work:

```
>>> plt.xaxis.set_major_formatter(FuncFormatter(myfunc)) 
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module> 
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'xaxis'
```

What should I do here?

Comment: I wish I could upvote this multiple times... I have yet to "break beneath the surface" and really understand the reasoning behind subplots and figures and why subplots seem to have more "power" i.e. ability to configure, etc.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If the figure that you want is selected, just use `gca()` to get the current axis instance:

```
ax = gca()
ax.xaxis.set_major_formatter(FuncFormatter(myfunc))
```

Comment: If you get an error `NameError: name 'gca' is not defined` try using `ax = plt.gca()` instead of `ax = gca()`

Answer (score 3):

Another option is to use the figure object returned by `figure()`.

```
fig = plt.figure()

# Create axes, either:
#  - Automatically with plotting code: plt.line(), plt.plot(), plt.bar(), etc
#  - Manually add axes: ax = fig.add_subplot(), ax = fig.add_axes()

fig.axes[0].get_xaxis().set_major_formatter(FuncFormatter(myfunc))
```

This option is very useful when you are handling several plots, as you can specify which plot will be updated.